# Adding an element to every item of an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, combinations

I currently have an input `[['a', [0, 1]], ['b', [1]]]`. I'm trying to combine the first item to every element in `[0,1]` i.e.: `'a'` in `['a',[0,1] => [['a',0],['a',1],['b',1]]` like ordered pairs. I've done it but it seems overly complicated I thought there might be a method I've overlooked.

```
[[0, [0, 1]], [1, [1]]].map.with_index{|x,y| x[1].map{|ele| [y,ele]}}.flatten(1)
#I used 'a'&'b' in the example to help with any confusion.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
▶ arr.flat_map { |e| [e.first].product(e.last) }
#⇒ [["a", 0], ["a", 1], ["b", 1]]
```

Comment: `flat_map` is an under-used gem, isn't it?

Comment: @tadman yes, it is, definitely. Basically, it’s a handy implementation of `reduce` as it would be done in more functional oriented languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [['a', [0, 1]], ['b', [1]]]

arr.each_with_object([]) { |(x,a),b| a.each { |y| b << [x,y] } }
  #=> [["a", 0], ["a", 1], ["b", 1]]
```